# How to determine if a relative difference is "big"?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, differences

I have two columns with the percentage of a certain variable, each column represents a different year. I calculate the relative difference in each category and I want to determine if this change is big based on the value of the first year.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{2020} & \text{2021} & \text{relative diff} \\ \hline
\text{Cat. 1} & 0.1 & 1 & 900\\ \hline
\text{Cat. 2} & 10& 8 & -20\\ \hline
\text{Cat. 3} & 55 & 53 & -3.63\\ \hline
\text{Cat. 4} & 34.9& 38 & 8.88\\ \hline
\text{Total} & 100 & 100 &\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

In the first row we have a very big relative difference, but since the category doesn't represent that much, I wouldn't consider it big.

I have tried different approaches, but they do not convince me, I would like to know if you use any method. Thank you!

Comment: Because "big" has neither any inherent meaning nor a standard statistical meaning, it is hard to know what you're trying to ask.  You phrase this question in terms of what *you* would "consider."  What could we possibly add to that?  Could you help us understand what you mean?

Comment: afaik this is not a statistics question. typically people might add an offset eg ( A-B)/(A+offset) where offset is the smallest absolute value you are interested in (1?5?  in your case). adding a 1 makes little difference when A is > say 5 but avoids you reporting huge relative differences. 900 -> 82 and -20 -> -18

Comment: I am referring to the mixed error https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs6210-f16/lec/2016-09-02.pdf ( acts like absolute error for small quantities)